# Registering all templates in folder /_controltempaltes/custom

Tags: master-page, user-controls

I have a question regarding the directives in the MasterPage. So if I deploy a custom template to ControlTemplates in SharePoint folder, to use it I
will need to write a directive which imports that control. It is clear, but the question is:

How can I import all my custom templates from a folder controltempaltes?

I tried:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="src" src="~/_controltemplates/CUSTOMTemplates" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="src" src="~/_controltemplates/CUSTOMTemplates/*" %>
```

Without success
...

Comment: That's not how ASP.NET controls are included using the Register Prefix. You can only register one ASCX control at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The syntax for [@ Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1(v=vs.90).aspx) with a user control is:

```
<%@ Register tagprefix="tagprefix"
   tagname="tagname"
   src="pathname" %>
```

Where

> src
>
> > The location (relative or absolute) of the declarative ASP.NET User Controls **file** to associate with the tagprefix:tagname pair.
>
> tagname
>
> > An arbitrary alias to associate with a class. This attribute is only used for user controls.
>
> tagprefix
>
> > An arbitrary alias that provides a shorthand reference to the namespace of the markup being used in the file that contains the directive.

Note the singular `file`.

Comment: Ok thank you, I hoped it was possible but it seems not. What I do like that at least registering one src path to my custom controls which are not user controls but server controls (webcontrols) does not require one by one registering

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you have to add each control template separately. Another option would be to write code which iterates through all your custom control templates and add them programmatically, wrapping this code in one control template.

Comment: Thanks but it is probably overhead